# Django creation of new user failed

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm facing some difficulties while trying to create a new user using UserCreationForm in Django.
I think that the issue is on the signup HTML page, but I can't really understand what am I doing wrong.
When I click submit after filling the required fields nothing happens.
I hope you could help me out.

Part of **signup.html**:

```
<div class="container">
                                <form id="register-form" method="post">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    {% for field in form %}

                                        {% if field.name == 'first_name' %}
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <input id="register-first_name" type="text" name="registerFirst" required
                                                   class="input-material">
                                            <label for="register-first_name" class="label-material">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                                          </div>
                                        {% endif %}


                                        {% if field.name == 'last_name' %}
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <input id="register-last_name" type="text" name="registerLast" required
                                                   class="input-material">
                                            <label for="register-last_name" class="label-material">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                                          </div>
                                        {% endif %}


                                        {% if field.name == 'username' %}
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <input id="username" type="text" name="username" required
                                                   class="input-material">
                                            <label for="username" class="label-material">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                                          </div>
                                        {% endif %}



                                        {% if field.name == 'email' %}
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <input id="register-email" type="text" name="registerEmail" required
                                                   class="input-material">
                                            <label for="register-email" class="label-material">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                                          </div>
                                        {% endif %}



                                        {% if field.name == 'password' %}
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <input id={{ form.name.name }} type="text" name="password" required
                                                   class="input-material">
                                            <label for={{ form.name.name }} class="label-material">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                                          </div>
                                        {% endif %}

                                    {% endfor %}

                                    <input id="register" type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">
                                </form>
                            <div/>
```

my **forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
```

my **views.py**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login as login_a
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from movie.forms import SignUpForm


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request,'login.html')

def logout(request):
    return render(request,'logout.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            print (username);
            print (raw_password);
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login_a(request, user)
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 3):

Your form looks incorrect. You are using incorrect values for the names (e.g. `name="registerFirst"` instead of `name="first_name"`), so the Django form will not use the submitted values. Then you are not displaying the field errors, so you don't get any useful feedback when you submit the form.

I would start by letting Django render the form. That will let you fix any problems in the view.

```
<form id="register-form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input id="register" type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

To help debugging, you can print values in your view, for example add `print(form.errors)` after the `if form.is_valid():` block.

Then, once the view is working with the simple template, you can render the fields manually if you need more control over the layout. See the docs on [rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) for more info. If you do this, remember to display any field/form errors to the user.

If you do render the fields manually, you can access the fields with `{{ form.first_name }}`, instead of looping through `{% for field in form %}` then having to check `field.name`.